# Como crear el archivo de produccion en react con webpack

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, webpack

Tengo una crud simple que la hice en react, el tema es que no use la herramienta **create-react-app**, sino que que lo hice desde cero con webpack y babel, etc. Mi problema es como poder crear la carpeta de produccion ya que con webpack solo lo hace en desarrollo. [Aca esta el link para ver los archivos en github por si sirve](https://github.com/lucas-98/tareas-react).Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente tienes que configurar Webpack en mi caso lo deje a si.

**package.json**

`"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js -p",
}`

**webpack.config.prod.js**

`const path = require('path');
const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, 'src');
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: path.resolve(sourcePath, 'index.js'),
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
}`